# T-SQL Post-Deployment Script how to reference a variable

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd, dacpac, dac

I'm deployng DACPAC with with the following post-deployment script1:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], 
             SIZE = 100MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)
```

However, when I try to reference this post-deployment script2, deployment fails:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], 
             SIZE = $(size), MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)
```

So, my question is what is the correct syntax to pass as size?

I use this command to initiate the script (first script1 works, script2 doesn't)

```
$resourceGroup = "SQL1"
$vmName = "SQL1"
$storageName = "sql1artifactsstorage111"
$ConfigurationPath = "C:\DSC\Ext\deployDB.ps1"
$ConfigurationName = "deployDB"
$configurationArchive = "deployDB.ps1.zip"
#Publish the configuration script into user storage
Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration -ConfigurationPath $ConfigurationPath -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -StorageAccountName $storageName -force
#Set the VM to run the DSC configuration
$configurationArguments = 
@{
    Credential = Get-Credential;
    DatabaseName = 'Database1' 
    size = '100MB'
}
Set-AzureRmVmDscExtension -Version 2.22 -Name dscExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName -ArchiveStorageAccountName $storageName -ArchiveBlobName $configurationArchive -AutoUpdate:$true -ConfigurationName $ConfigurationName -ConfigurationArgument $configurationArguments
```

This is the error DSC shows:

```
Dac Deploy Failed: 'Exception calling "Deploy" 
with "3" argument(s): "An error occurred during deployment plan generation. 
Deployment cannot continue."'
```

Comment: Do you have multiple files tagged as "Post-Deploy"? You should only have one post-deploy file and use a :r tag to include other files to run in that post-deploy script.

Comment: I have only 1 post-deployment script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is the last refuge of the scoundrel:

```
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] MODIFY FILE (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)],SIZE = $(size), MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)');
GO
```

worked for me, albeit in a local deployment rather than through Azure DSC.

This is a general purpose technique for doing these "DBA-esque" activities that often don't support TSQL variable substitution.

---

Note to future readers: this trick apparently worked, which is to say the OP has marked it as the answer. However, it was *probably* only necessary due to differing versions of DacFX between the workstation and the build server, see for example [another SO post relating to the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628071/database-deployment-an-error-occurred-during-deployment-plan-generation-deplo).